# Vue.js and svg modules and mismatched nodes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg

Let's say I have two vue modules:

`parentModule.vue`

```
<template>
  <svg>
    <child-module v-for="i in ['a', 'b']" :key="i"/>
  </svg>
</template>
...
```

`childModule.vue`

```
<template>
  <g>
    //...some valid svg content
  </g>
</template>
...
```

Now, it works decently. The issue is, unfortunately, that in development mode I get a warning about mismatched nodes - apparently Vue doesn't like using svg elements. I have a feeling it messes a bit with some things in development during re-rendering. Is there any way around this?

---

## Edit

After dabbling for a bit it seems the issue might be with something different - on a line of how `canvas` property is being updated. As I couldn't replicate it in CodePen (I guess  version of vue might have a different logging level?), here is a working example: https://github.com/msdsk/so_svg_example

Comment: Can you post a working example ?

Comment: @Marc added in an edit

Comment: This seems to me like a SSR issue coming from nuxt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example the problem is due to the usage of `Math.random()` in `pages/index.vue` (and has nothing to do with SVG). As a result the server-side rendered page doesn't match the virtual DOM produced on the client-side, leading to the observed warning during hydration.

From the [Vue SSR documentation](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/hydration.html):

> Hydration refers to the client-side process during which Vue takes over the static HTML sent by the server and turns it into dynamic DOM that can react to client-side data changes.
>
> ...
>
> In development mode, Vue will assert the client-side generated virtual DOM tree matches the DOM structure rendered from the server. If there is a mismatch, it will bail hydration, discard existing DOM and render from scratch.